# Double slash issue in Codeigniter URL

Tags: php, url, codeigniter-3

I am facing double slash issue in codeigniter url which seems like

`http://localhost/school/admin//categories/add`

My `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/school/admin/';`

By removing of end slash same double slashes shows i mean (`$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/school/admin';`)

Also by making blank `$config['base_url'] = '';`  same issue of double remain.

And my htaccess is as

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Kindly help me where the issue is occurring.

Comment: Try `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]` instead of `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]`  in .htaccess

Comment: Same double slash issue with changing /$1 to $1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using admin_url(); in the url helper.which has already the back slash.so when i use admin_url().'/categories/add' this generate double slash.so solved simply removing the one custom back slash.i.e admin_url().'categories/add'